# Calculating distance between point layer to n nearest polylines using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, line, nearest-neighbor

In QGIS I am trying to calculate the distance from a point layer to a polyline layer for the n nearest polylines. I have figured out how to calculate this distance to the centroid of the polylines using the point to hub tool, but I need the distance to the edge of the closest polylines - not centroids. I can calculate the nearest polyline by dumping the polylines to nodes and calculating to nearest point, but that method falls apart for the n nearest calculation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **NNJoin** plugin to calculate the distance between points and its nearest line. You can download the plugin via *Plugins* > *Manage and Install Plugins...*.

It is recommended, however, to not use this plugin on large datasets containing lines as it does not use a spatial index for lines.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me unfortunately. I am not trying to join the nearest line I am trying to join the N nearest lines. The nearest neighbor is easy in QGIS, but I need the 5 nearest neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

To get the nearest points go to `Processing`, search for `Nearest`, then `Join attributes by nearest`. You can then input your two vector layers and specify the max nearest neighbours to 5. It will show the distance between the vector layers too.